Uninstall last pip installed packages
I have just installed a package in my virtual environment which I shouldn't have installed. It also installed many dependency packages.
Is there a way to roll back and uninstall the package and its dependencies just installed?
Something like "uninstall packages installed in the last 1 hour" or a similar functionality.

Related: Pip: unistall ALL pkgs installed during -e installation

Could you clarify the reason you want to uninstall the packages? Virtual environments are cheap and temporary, so if there's a real need to remove those packages (e.g. they're malicious typo-squatters, they provide conflicting import packages, they depend on incompatible version of the package you do need, etc), then the easiest thing to do would be to just create a new virtual environment. Otherwise you can probably just ignore them.

@Brian61354270 I was trying some new stuff and I did it by accident in the virtual environment that I plan to deploy later as a website. So I don't want to deploy an environment with packages that are not used.
Not sure if this makes sense... Sorry I do website programming as a hobby and I do things in suboptimal ways :/

Below snippet can help you identify the recently installed pacakage. Once you have the list of packages, you can manually uninstall that pacakge.
import pkg_resources
import os
import time

for package in pkg_resources.working_set:
    print("%s: %s" % (package, time.ctime(os.path.getctime(package.location))))

